# Can I increase the height of the LinearLayout as the EditTextView inside the LinearLayout grows?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

The EditTextView is inside a LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/memoInputLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/box_two_unfocused"
    android:minHeight="64dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Today"
        android:textColor="#007BFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="input memo"
        android:textColorHint="#007BFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Of course, as text is entered into the EditTextView, multiple lines are being entered. However, I want the height of the LinearLayout to increase as the line of the EditTextView gets longer vertically. When executed with the above code, only the line length of the EditTextView is increased vertically, and the height of the LinearLayout has not changed. How to fix it?

Comment: Set your editText height to `wrap content` as well.

Comment: If you set `EditText` height to wrap_content you may find your layout spreading outside the screen when input is super large. So, consider making `LinearLayout` `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to let it spread and keep `EditText` wrap_content